# Redirect all web traffic except a few dirs/paths?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-server

I have a website that I need to redirect almost everything to another domain, except for a few directories/paths. The server is running ColdFusion and IIS in a hosting environment.

Functionality:

```
a) http://example1.com redirects to http://example2.com
b) http://example1.com/special stays put
c) http://example1.com/anydir redirects to http://example2.com
```

Any suggestions for how I can accomplish this?

I considered doing it in ColdFusion, but this won't handle case c). URL Rewrite in IIS isn't possible, because this is a limitation in the hosting provider.

edit:

I just realized that the functionality above does not explicitly state this case:

```
d) http://example1.com/anydir/anydir redirects to http://example2.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this a while back to redirect an existing application from an old path to its new path. I believe it relies on subfolders to be in existence, for example "anydir/anydir/" must actually be real folders. I essentially just paste it into an existing application folder so config, application and index files are overwritten and then redirects take place based on definitions in config.

The redirect definitions are regex so can actually get quite complicated if necessary. It is an ordered array so you can put more specific redirects first and the more general ones at the end. You can either include a "last resort" redirect at the end or allow an error to occur if no definitions match--just depends on how precise you want to be.

*config/config.cfm*

```
<cfset config = {
    debug=true
    , redirects = [
        {find="^/path/temp/dir2/(.+)$", replace="http://temp.domain.com/dir2\1"}
        , {find="^/path/temp/(.+)$", replace="http://temp.domain.com/\1"}            
    ]
} />
```

*index.cfm*

```
[blank file]
```

*Application.cfc*

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset this.name="Redirect#hash(getCurrentTemplatePath())#"/>

    <cfinclude template="config/config.cfm" />

    <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
        <cfset redirect(cgi.path_info) />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onMissingTemplate">
        <cfargument name="targetPage" required="true" />
        <cfset redirect(arguments.targetPage) />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="redirect">
        <cfargument name="targetPage" required="true" />

        <cfset var i = 0 />
        <cfset var newpath = "" />

        <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(variables.config.redirects)#" index="i">
            <cfif refindnocase(variables.config.redirects[i].find, arguments.targetPage)>
                <cfset newpath = rereplacenocase(arguments.targetPage, variables.config.redirects[i].find, variables.config.redirects[i].replace) />
                <cfif len(cgi.query_string)>
                    <cfset newpath &= "?" & cgi.query_string />
                </cfif>

                <cfif variables.config.debug>
                    <cfoutput>#newpath#</cfoutput>
                    <cfabort>
                </cfif>

                <cflocation url="#newpath#" addtoken="false" />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>

        <cfthrow type="custom.redirect.notfound" />
        <cfabort>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better handling redirects with the server if you can, but if you can you could do it with CF with something like this..  how you structure really depends on what the actual URLs you need to handle are..

You could likely handle case (c) with Regular Expressions..

```
<!---get the current URL--->
<cfset currentURL = "#cgi.server_name##cgi.path_info#" > 

<!---based on the URL, redirect accordingly--->
<cfif FindNoCase("example1.com/special", currentURL)>
    <!---do nothing--->
<cfelseif FindNoCase("example1.com", currentURL)>
    <cflocation url="http://www.example2.com" >
</cfif>
```

Comment: I attempted to add a variation on that in Application.cfm so that it is always processed, to ensure all requests get forwarded except for the excluded ones. However it did not work. Is Application.cfm not the right place to do it?

Comment: Application.cfm is a good place to put it..   to make sure it is getting run, just output some labels above and below the block to see if they are being output.... try outputting the #currentURL# to see what it reads.. play around with it.. it should work..